# Wordpress Archives Title Issue

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, page-title

I'm using this code to display the category title on the Archives page of my website.

```
<h2><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></h2>
```

The above code works perfectly for displaying the category title.

> Eg: website.com/category/question

On this page the `h1` title is 'Question', which is right!

But the issue I'm facing, it doesn't display the tag title. Instead, it only displays the Category title on the tag page.

> Eg: website.com/tag/howto

On this page the h1 title remains 'Question', which is wrong! I want it to display the H1 title "eg. How-to"

Is there any way to modify the above code to display the tag title as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic solution would be to `get_queried_object` instead of the Category.  Then use the property `name`

```
<h2><?php $object = get_queried_object(); echo $object->name; ?></h2>
```

You could also do something specific for a tag like this.

```
<?php
$object = get_queried_object();
if (is_a($object, 'WP_TERM')){
    if ($object->taxonomy === 'post_tag') {
        // Do something specific for a tag
        echo $object->name;
    }
}?>
```

Or simply use
`is_tag()` or `is_category()` to determine what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Code worked perfectly <h2><?php $object = get_queried_object(); echo $object->name; ?></h2>